# Timed images change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I've done some research and I cannot find a solution on the internet as of yet.

I've built a website and I'm trying to get a background image to change after 3 seconds, once changed it stays on the second image, no infinite loop.

I realise it can be done with CSS3, but the website needs to be widely compatible, so I'm guessing JQuery/JS is the best solution? if so, how do I go about implementing it?

### EDIT

Here is the code I am using

```
<script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById(header).style.background = "url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/girl-color.jpg)";
        }, 3000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header" style="background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/girl-bw.jpg);">
```

But I have this error.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: u have to use jquery plugins for this purpose...

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla no you don't

Comment: What do you mean you have done some research? If you google "Timed images change" the first 4 results are 4 correct ways of doing it

Comment: Yes but I'm unsure about the infinite looping.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JS, assuming the background is tied to the body:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     document.body.style.background = "url(here_goes_the_url)";
}, 3000);
```

Comment: +1 nice to go vanilla when you can ;)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer jQuery, how about the following:

```
$(function(){ //Document ready
    setTimeout(function(){ // 3000 miliseconds (3 seconds)
        $('body').css('background-image', "url('new_bg.jog')"); // this will change the bg for the body element, modify for your target element
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I seem to be getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery properly included? Also, it might be in noConflict mode, so try changing all the $ to jQuery like

jQuery(function(){...})